# Drag page content view make a blank screen on iOS 8 mobile app

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, swipe, ionic-framework

In ionic ios app swipe the page it shows blank screen.Please help me how to fix this.

app.js

```
 $stateProvider.state('login',
      {
          cache: false,
          url: '/login',
          templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
          controller: 'loginCtrl'

      })
```

this is Login.html template page

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true" padding="true">

<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">

    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true">
       <form name="signInForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="tryLogin(signInForm)">
        <div class="list-header">
            <label class="item item-input" tabs-item-hide="true" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : signInForm.Email.$invalid, 'no-errors' : signInForm.Email.$valid}">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" ng-model="loginData.Email" autofocus required>
            </label>
            <span class="form-errors" ng-show="signInForm.Email.$error && signInForm.$submitted" ng-messages="signInForm.Email.$error" ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">

            </span>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password" ng-model="loginData.Password" required>
            </label>
            <span class="form-errors" ng-show="signInForm.Password.$error && signInForm.$submitted" ng-messages="signInForm.Password.$error" ng-messages-include="templates/form-errors.html">

            </span>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <p class="text_right">
                <a href="#/forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
            </p>
            <div>
                <button class="button button-block button-positive">Login</button>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align: center">
                <a href="#/SignUp">Create an account</a>

            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

My Main Page HTML:

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
         </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left" >
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
            <h1 class="title">MY App</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" nav-clear menu-close href="#/Settings">
                    <i class="icon ion-gear-b"></i>Settings
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Now swipe the child page it from the iphone it show the blank screen, coldn't load it again
[image]

Answer (score 4):

just use the following line of code in the config of your AngularJS module

```
angular.module(....)
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider){
$ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
//remaining code in config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an issue was created on [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/3216) and the cash being disabled was identified as the cause of the problem. moreover a reply from the ionic team came as follow *(last reply on github)*

> This is caused by caching being disabled. There is big benefit of caching you views, and an edge case like this isn't something we want to support.
>
> If you're worried about data not being updated, you can use the view
>   lifecycle events to make sure data is up to date.

so if you need the caching disabled and you don't care about this feature you can disable it as @Arul said. if you want this feature you have to enable caching.